# Appending different size font in a custom label

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

I have created a label that displays a high score. I want to add the units ft to the end since the the score is a distance. I am using a custom font and simply adding ft to the end of the end results in FT which is to big due to the font size and font. I am wonder if i can reduce the font size and add it to the end.

This is the code i have so far:

```
    var highscoreLabel:SKLabelNode!

    highscoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Komika Axis")
    highscoreLabel.fontSize = 16
    highscoreLabel.zPosition = 5
    highscoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.addChild(highscoreLabel)

    var highscoreShow = defaults.integerForKey("RegularHighscore")

    highscoreLabel.text = "High score: \(highscoreShow)" 
   // High Score: \(highscoreShow) (ft in a smaller font size)"
```

I want to add ft in a smaller font size than the rest of the text in the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributed string will help there:

```
var ftString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"ft", attributes:[NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Komika Axis", size: 10.0)])

highscoreLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"\(highscoreShow)").appendAttributedString(ftString)
```

Comment: I see what you have done but i want to add "ft" to the highscore label text but in a smaller font size without creating a separate label

Comment: Is there any chance you also know how to do this in sprite kit with an SKLabelNode? @nicael

Comment: @Nfi sklabelnode doesn't support attributed strings.